# Clutch is stuck disengaged and pedal will not move

Tags: toyota, clutch, corolla

My clutch pedal on my 2005 Toyota Corolla will not move. I can start the car by pressing the clutch safety switch by hand.

I can put my transmission into gear with the engine running, so the clutch must be stuck in the disengaged position. So there is something wrong with my hydraulic clutch system but I have no idea what.

What should I look at?

Comment: I would say it is something with your hydraulic clutch system as you've suggested. I'm surprised it is stuck in the disenganged position ... normally it would be the other way around (no clutch release at all). Sounds like the slave cylinder is stuck all the way out. If it were, it might also be why you cannot depress the clutch pedal. I don't know for sure as I've never ran into your issue, but it seems plausible.

Comment: Hey @travis as a side note.  here's a link to the tour page for stack exchange.  have a look.  http://wackybee.sun.macserver.jp/WackyPAGE/2d/non/dec/ygs1000_03.jpg  and welcome.  Thanks for the question and the contribution.  See you around.

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot of information to go by. Did this happen suddenly? Gradually? It could be a misadjusted clutch pedal/master cylinder actuator rod. Try pulling up on the clutch pedal to see if it releases.  If not, locate the clutch master cylinder under the hood, or the slave cylinder on the transmission bell housing and loosen the line at the master, or the bleeder valve at the slave. If fluid comes out under pressure, check to see if he clutch now works. If it does, you have a pedal to master cylinder adjustment issue not allowing the fluid to return to the master cylinder reservoir.

If this doesn't help, you probably have a mechanical issue, like a clutch disk or pressure plate problem, or even a release bearing slide stuck. Good luck!  Let us know iWhat fixes it.